Same matplotlib and numpy versions, but different python versions result in different plots
numpy                     1.26.4
matplotlib                3.8.3
In python 3.8, the graph is drawn correctly, but in 3.12 the graph is not only distorted but the x-axis label cannot be changed!
code is here:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure(figsize=(13, 4))

labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5']
first = [20, 34, 30, 35, 27]
second = [25, 32, 34, 20, 25]
third = [21, 31, 37, 21, 28]
fourth = [26, 31, 35, 27, 21]


plt.subplot(131)
x = np.arange(len(labels))  # x轴刻度标签位置
width = 0.25  # 柱子的宽度

plt.bar(x - width/2, first, width, label='1')
plt.bar(x + width/2, second, width, label='2')
plt.ylabel('Scores')
plt.title('2 datasets')

plt.xticks(x, labels=labels)
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(132)
x = np.arange(len(labels))  
width = 0.25 

plt.bar(x - width, first, width, label='1')
plt.bar(x, second, width, label='2')
plt.bar(x + width, third, width, label='3')
plt.ylabel('Scores')
plt.title('3 datasets')

plt.xticks(x, labels=labels)
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(133)
x = np.arange(len(labels)) 
width = 0.2 

plt.bar(x - 1.5*width, first, width, label='1')
plt.bar(x - 0.5*width, second, width, label='2')
plt.bar(x + 0.5*width, third, width, label='3')
plt.bar(x + 1.5*width, fourth, width, label='4')
plt.ylabel('Scores')
plt.title('4 datasets')

plt.xticks(x, labels=labels)
plt.legend()

plt.show()

Only the Python version is different in the version premise of the imported package, so why is this causing the problem?

Sorry I don't have enough reputation to be able to upload images, specifically the problem is that under version 3.12 the images are distorted and the x-axis labels can't be replaced with [‘G1’, ‘G2’, ‘G3’, ‘G4’, ‘G5’] but instead [0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0] like this

How are you installing these packages?  Matplotlib 3.8.3 and Numpy 1.26.4 require at least python 3.9.

I can't see your problem, I ran your code, and the output seems fine, the labels are changed and the bar charts look normal, using Python 3.12.5.

I also used the same versions of numpy and matplotlib as you did.
EDIT:
However, in your version (i.e., Python), you might need to use ax.set_xticks() and ax.set_xticklabels() instead of plt.xticks() to correctly set the x-axis labels.
You can also implement a loop to make the code shorter.
Something like this should work:
 #your code (data)
    
    widths = [0.25, 0.25, 0.2]

for i in range(3):
    ax = plt.subplot(1, 3, i+1)
    x = np.arange(len(labels))
    width = widths[i]
    for j in range(i+2):
        ax.bar(x + (j - (i+1)/2) * width, data[j], width, label=f'{j+1}')
    ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
    ax.set_title(f'{i+2} datasets')
    ax.set_xticks(x)
    ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
    ax.legend()

plt.show()


Thanks for your reply, firstly I think the problem should not be in plt.xticks() as I can draw the same graph as you using python version 3.8. But in 3.12 the graph is stretched vertically and the labels G1/G2/G3/G4/G5 are displayed as 0.0/1.0/2.0/3.0/4.0. I made sure that both interpreters have the same version of numpy and matplotlib but still the problem occurs. I guess the problem might be the python version, if you have any other ideas feel free to provide them.

I see, but you have a problem with setting the tick labels, which is also different from the code I provided. Have you tried running my code? By the way, why don't you update your Python to 3.12.5, which is the latest version to my knowledge?

yes,i have tried your code.
like this:
data = [first, second, third, fourth]
Then is the code you provide.
But the result is still the same, with 3.12 python the image is distorted and the lable is not displayed correctly.
After ensuring that the np and plt versions are the same, I initially thought it was a python version issue, but you say you can run it correctly. I'm just confused about this, and although I can fix it by changing the interpreter, I'd still like to know what the problem is.

It still can be a bug in your version of Python. I don't have more knowledge regarding the previous versions of Python than what I have already shared, sorry
